# BizTalk WCF-WebHttp mapping form-data variable from multi-occurrence nodes

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

My client's API requires variable data to be delivered to them via HTTP POST.  Some of this data is mapped to the URL and some of the data is in the message body form variables:

```
Url: http://myclientapi.com/poNumber/111222/complete

Message body variables: carrier=FEDEX&trackingNumber=4XXXXXX&shipDate=2018-12-17
```

WCF-WebHttp port seems to be the ticket.  It is easy enough to define a flat file schema for the message body variables (carrier, trackingNumber and shipDate).

[image: btsnip]

My problem is the URL variable mapping for poNumber in the send port configuration.  I want to do something like this:

```
<BtsHttpUrlMapping>
    <Operation Name = "POSHIPPED" Method="POST" Url="/poNumber/{poNumber}/complete"/>
</BtsHttpUrlMapping>
```

Given that only single occurrence nodes can be promoted via property schema I can't map the poNumber data to the same nodes that I map the message body variables, nor do I want the poNumber name/value included in the message body.

Have I reached the limitations of this particular adapter?

Comment: So where is the poNumber coming from?  it is a bit unclear.  Can you give us a sample payload? e.g. the Payload before you map to it your HttpRequest body.  And no, I don't think you have reached a limitation, you can probably define a Message Context Only promoted property for the poNumber.

Comment: Please clarify one point.  The API is single instance (of a PO) so you shouldn't have repeating PO numbers to begin with.  Seems that the real problem.

Comment: Hi Johns-305.  I do not have repeating PO numbers in my input message.  I have one value that needs to be sent to client's API as part of the URL, but that value can't appear in the message body itself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the repeating node you are talking about is in the destination schema going to the WCF-WebHttp adatper, and that the poNumber is in a non-repeating node on a schema that you are mapping from.

What you need to do is to create a Property Schema where you define the poNumber as MessageContextPropertyBase

**Property Schema**

[image: MessageContextPropertyBase]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Scratch.SO53891801propertyschema" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://Scratch.SO53891801propertyschema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:schemaInfo schema_type="property" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="poNumber" type="xs:string">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:fieldInfo propertyGuid="3acc0f2f-64b0-4057-bc59-b8c76ab220a1" propSchFieldBase="MessageContextPropertyBase" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

You add this property schema your input schema. From your input where your orderNumber is in a non-repeating node, you link the poNumber to the property.

**Sample input schema**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Scratch.SO53891801_input" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns:ns0="http://Scratch.SO53891801propertyschema" targetNamespace="http://Scratch.SO53891801_input" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:imports>
        <b:namespace prefix="ns0" uri="http://Scratch.SO53891801propertyschema" location=".\SO53891801propertyschema.xsd" />
      </b:imports>
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:properties>
          <b:property name="ns0:poNumber" xpath="/*[local-name()='Root' and namespace-uri()='http://Scratch.SO53891801_input']/*[local-name()='poNumber' and namespace-uri()='']" />
        </b:properties>
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="poNumber" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="carrier" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="trackingNumber" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="shipDate" type="xs:date" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**Sample input file**

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://Scratch.SO53891801_input">
  <poNumber>poNumber_0</poNumber>
  <carrier>carrier_0</carrier>
  <trackingNumber>trackingNumber_0</trackingNumber>
  <shipDate>1999-05-31</shipDate>
</ns0:Root>
```

**Sample output schema**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Scratch.SO53891801" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://Scratch.SO53891801" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="HttpRequestBody">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="FromValue">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Create a map between the two.

**Map**

[image: Map]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<mapsource Name="BizTalk Map" Version="2" BizTalkServerMapperTool_Version="3.0" XRange="100" YRange="420" OmitXmlDeclaration="Yes" UseXSLTransform="Undefined" TreatElementsAsRecords="No" OptimizeValueMapping="Yes" GenerateDefaultFixedNodes="Yes" PreserveSequenceOrder="No" IgnoreNamespacesForLinks="Yes" method="xml" CopyPIs="No" xmlVersion="1.0">
    <SrcTree RootNode_Name="Root">
        <Reference Location=".\SO53891801-input.xsd" />
    </SrcTree>
    <TrgTree RootNode_Name="HttpRequestBody">
        <Reference Location=".\SO53891801.xsd" />
    </TrgTree>
    <ScriptTypePrecedence>
        <CSharp Enabled="Yes" />
        <ExternalAssembly Enabled="Yes" />
        <VbNet Enabled="Yes" />
        <JScript Enabled="Yes" />
        <XsltCallTemplate Enabled="Yes" />
        <Xslt Enabled="Yes" />
    </ScriptTypePrecedence>
    <TreeValues>
        <TestValues />
        <ConstantValues />
    </TreeValues>
    <Pages>
        <Page Name="Page 1">
            <Links>
                <Link LinkID="1" LinkFrom="/*[local-name()='&lt;Schema&gt;']/*[local-name()='Root']/*[local-name()='carrier']" LinkTo="1" />
                <Link LinkID="2" LinkFrom="/*[local-name()='&lt;Schema&gt;']/*[local-name()='Root']/*[local-name()='trackingNumber']" LinkTo="1" />
                <Link LinkID="3" LinkFrom="/*[local-name()='&lt;Schema&gt;']/*[local-name()='Root']/*[local-name()='shipDate']" LinkTo="1" />
                <Link LinkID="4" LinkFrom="/*[local-name()='&lt;Schema&gt;']/*[local-name()='Root']/*[local-name()='carrier']" LinkTo="/*[local-name()='&lt;Schema&gt;']/*[local-name()='HttpRequestBody']/*[local-name()='FromValue']/*[local-name()='Value']" />
                <Link LinkID="5" LinkFrom="/*[local-name()='&lt;Schema&gt;']/*[local-name()='Root']/*[local-name()='trackingNumber']" LinkTo="/*[local-name()='&lt;Schema&gt;']/*[local-name()='HttpRequestBody']/*[local-name()='FromValue']/*[local-name()='Value']" />
                <Link LinkID="6" LinkFrom="/*[local-name()='&lt;Schema&gt;']/*[local-name()='Root']/*[local-name()='shipDate']" LinkTo="/*[local-name()='&lt;Schema&gt;']/*[local-name()='HttpRequestBody']/*[local-name()='FromValue']/*[local-name()='Value']" />
                <Link LinkID="7" LinkFrom="/*[local-name()='&lt;Schema&gt;']/*[local-name()='Root']/*[local-name()='carrier']" LinkTo="/*[local-name()='&lt;Schema&gt;']/*[local-name()='HttpRequestBody']/*[local-name()='FromValue']/*[local-name()='Id']" Compiler-Copy-Directive="CopyName" />
                <Link LinkID="8" LinkFrom="/*[local-name()='&lt;Schema&gt;']/*[local-name()='Root']/*[local-name()='trackingNumber']" LinkTo="/*[local-name()='&lt;Schema&gt;']/*[local-name()='HttpRequestBody']/*[local-name()='FromValue']/*[local-name()='Id']" Compiler-Copy-Directive="CopyName" />
                <Link LinkID="9" LinkFrom="/*[local-name()='&lt;Schema&gt;']/*[local-name()='Root']/*[local-name()='shipDate']" LinkTo="/*[local-name()='&lt;Schema&gt;']/*[local-name()='HttpRequestBody']/*[local-name()='FromValue']/*[local-name()='Id']" Compiler-Copy-Directive="CopyName" />
                <Link LinkID="10" LinkFrom="1" LinkTo="/*[local-name()='&lt;Schema&gt;']/*[local-name()='HttpRequestBody']/*[local-name()='FromValue']" />
            </Links>
            <Functoids>
                <Functoid FunctoidID="1" Functoid-FID="424" X-Cell="53" Y-Cell="173">
                    <Input-Parameters>
                        <Parameter Type="link" Value="1" linkIndex="0" Guid="7932e28c-0c98-4f47-aea8-f9a3a709eef0" />
                        <Parameter Type="link" Value="2" linkIndex="1" Guid="44112afb-3729-4d14-ba00-9053c96964a4" />
                        <Parameter Type="link" Value="3" linkIndex="2" Guid="eaecaba3-61c0-4cea-ae1b-16316322cea6" />
                    </Input-Parameters>
                </Functoid>
            </Functoids>
        </Page>
    </Pages>
</mapsource>
```

**Context property in message**
From the input schema it will promote the property, and it will still exist after the map has executed.

Showing the Context Property still exists after the map on the send port

[image: Context Property]

Comment: Thanks Dijkgraaf for taking the time to respond with such useful detail.  I was not aware that the context property could be set in this manner.  It did not, however, resolve my issue.  The value does indeed map correctly to the URL as described, however it also appears in the message body which is a problem.  When i push my message out a flat flle pipeline:  Exepected:  carrier=FEDEX&trackingNumber=4XXXXXX&shipDate=2018-12-17......Actual: 111111111carrier=FEDEX&trackingNumber=4XXXXXX&shipDate=2018-12-17    (111111111 being the order number.... should map to URL only, not message)

Comment: @DougGriffin  Then you have an issue in your map that creates the payload.  Can you add the details of your map to the question and a sample payload, and the output (desired vs actual as per your comment)?  If you look at my map, I'm not mapping the  PO number to the output message.  Maybe also the configuration on your send port.